# how to send multiple number as input using curl?

Tags: php, curl, urlencode

i want to send multiple number as input using curl.For this i'm using num[] as in html code.This is my code

```
   $num[]=$_POST["num"];
 $msg=$_POST["msg"];    
$url = 'http://localhost/s/a.php';
$fields = array(
'num'=>urlencode($_POST["num"]),
'msg'=>urlencode($_POST["msg"]));

$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields);
$re = curl_exec($ch);
```

But it shows an error

```
Warning: urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
```

Comment: 1. `$_POST["num"]` or `$_POST["num"]`, either or both of them are array. 2. Why are you doing `$num[] = $_POST["num"];`? You can simply do `$num = $_POST["num"];`

Comment: 3. You won't get anything in `$re` unless you set this as well, `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` 4. `CURLOPT_POST` doesn't take integer as value, like `count($fields)`, it should be `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);`

Comment: i have solved it,thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `urlencode()` the values of the `$fields` array.  `http_build_query()` will perform this for you properly.

Also `urlencode()` only works on strings, not arrays of values (hence the error).  Finally, if you were able to encode them before passing them into `http_build_query`, you're now urlencoding already urlencoded strings--the result will likely be garbage.

Try this:

```
 $fields = array(
      'num'=>$_POST["num"],
      'msg'=>$_POST["msg"]);

 $fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
```